# Building queries dynamically in rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

Im trying to replicate the searching list style of crunchbase using ruby on rails.
I have an array of filters that looks something like this:

```
[
   {
      "id":"0",
      "className":"Company",
      "field":"name",
      "operator":"starts with",
      "val":"a"
   },
   {
      "id":"1",
      "className":"Company",
      "field":"hq_city",
      "operator":"equals",
      "val":"Karachi"
   },
   {
      "id":"2",
      "className":"Category",
      "field":"name",
      "operator":"does not include",
      "val":"ECommerce"
   }
]
```

I send this json string to my ruby controller where I have implemented this logic:

```
filters = params[:q]
table_names = {}
filters.each do |filter|
    filter = filters[filter]
    className = filter["className"]
    fieldName = filter["field"]
    operator = filter["operator"]
    val = filter["val"]
    if table_names[className].blank? 
        table_names[className] = []
    end
    table_names[className].push({
        fieldName: fieldName,
        operator: operator,
        val: val
    })
end

table_names.each do |k, v|
    i = 0
    where_string = ''
    val_hash = {}
    v.each do |field|
        if i > 0
            where_string += ' AND '
        end
        where_string += "#{field[:fieldName]} = :#{field[:fieldName]}"
        val_hash[field[:fieldName].to_sym] = field[:val]
        i += 1
    end
    className = k.constantize
    puts className.where(where_string, val_hash)
end
```

What I do is, I loop over the json array and create a hash with keys as table names and values are the array with the name of the column, the operator and the value to apply that operator on. So I would have something like this after the `table_names` hash is created:

```
{
   'Company':[
      {
         fieldName:'name',
         operator:'starts with',
         val:'a'
      },
      {
         fieldName:'hq_city',
         operator:'equals',
         val:'karachi'
      }
   ],
   'Category':[
      {
         fieldName:'name',
         operator:'does not include',
         val:'ECommerce'
      }
   ]
}
```

Now I loop over the table_names hash and create a where query using the `Model.where("column_name = :column_name", {column_name: 'abcd'})` syntax.

So I would be generating two queries:

```
SELECT "companies".* FROM "companies" WHERE (name = 'a' AND hq_city = 'b')
SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE (name = 'c')
```

I have two problems now:

**1. Operators:**

I have many operators that can be applied on a column like 'starts with', 'ends with', 'equals', 'does not equals', 'includes', 'does not includes', 'greater than', 'less than'. I am guessing the best way would be to do a switch case on the operator and use the appropriate symbol while building the where string. So for example, if the operator is 'starts with', i'd do something like `where_string += "#{field[:fieldName]} like %:#{field[:fieldName]}"` and likewise for others.

So is this approach correct and is this type of wildcard syntax allowed in this kind of `.where`?

**2. More than 1 table**

As you saw, my approach builds 2 queries for more than 2 tables. I do not need 2 queries, I need the category name to be in the same query where the category belongs to the company.

Now what I want to do is I need to create a query like this:

```
Company.joins(:categories).where("name = :name and hq_city = :hq_city and categories.name = :categories[name]", {name: 'a', hq_city: 'Karachi', categories: {name: 'ECommerce'}})
```

But this is not it. The search can become very very complex. For example:

A Company has many FundingRound. FundingRound can have many Investment and Investment can have many IndividualInvestor. So I can select create a filter like:

```
{
  "id":"0",
  "className":"IndividualInvestor",
  "field":"first_name",
  "operator":"starts with",
  "val":"za"
}
```

My approach would create a query like this:

```
SELECT "individual_investors".* FROM "individual_investors" WHERE (first_name like %za%)
```

This query is wrong. I want to query the individual investors of the investments of the funding round of the company. Which is a lot of joining tables.

The approach that I have used is applicable to a single model and cannot solve the problem that I stated above.

How would I solve this problem?

Comment: So the search will always be in the `Company` context?

Comment: Why not include something like a `queryModel` in the JSON when the query is in the context of a relationed model?

Comment: @ErvalhouS no it wont be

Comment: Umm what would queryModel do?

Comment: It would represent the model that you will use to search the corresponding class, i.e.: a `Category` query with the `queryModel: 'Company'` would concatenate it's search for categories inside the company query, instead of creating results for categories, it would handle results for companies with those category matchers.

Comment: Can we able to add one more key and value into array ? like `operation`

Comment: Might it be easier to learn a few more details about SQL and skip the extra learning of the Ruby mapping?

Comment: @MayurShah yeap sure

Comment: @RickJames i didn't get you?

Comment: have you considered something like [ransack](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a SQL query based on your hash. The most generic approach is raw SQL, which can be executed by `ActiveRecord`.

Here is some concept code that should give you the right idea:

```
query_select = "select * from "
query_where = ""
tables = [] # for selecting from all tables
hash.each do |table, values|
  table_name = table.constantize.table_name
  tables << table_name
  values.each do |q|
    query_where += " AND " unless query_string.empty?
    query_where += "'#{ActiveRecord::Base.connection.quote(table_name)}'."
    query_where += "'#{ActiveRecord::Base.connection.quote(q[fieldName)}'"
    if q[:operator] == "starts with" # this should be done with an appropriate method
      query_where += " LIKE '#{ActiveRecord::Base.connection.quote(q[val)}%'"
    end
  end
end
query_tables = tables.join(", ")
raw_query = query_select + query_tables + " where " + query_where 
result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(raw_query)
result.to_h # not required, but raw results are probably easier to handle as a hash
```

What this does:

- `query_select` specifies what information you want in the result
- `query_where` builds all the search conditions and escapes input to prevent SQL injections
- `query_tables` is a list of all the tables you need to search
- `table_name = table.constantize.table_name` will give you the SQL table_name as used by the model
- `raw_query` is the actual combined sql query from the parts above
- `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(raw_query)` executes the sql on the database

**Make sure to put any user submitted input in quotes and escape it properly to prevent SQL injections.**

For your example the created query will look like this:

```
select * from companies, categories where 'companies'.'name' LIKE 'a%' AND 'companies'.'hq_city' = 'karachi' AND 'categories'.'name' NOT LIKE '%ECommerce%'
```

This approach might need additional logic for joining tables that are related.
In your case, if `company` and `category` have an association, you have to add something like this to the `query_where`

```
"AND 'company'.'category_id' = 'categories'.'id'"
```

**Easy approach:** You can create a Hash for all pairs of models/tables that can be queried and store the appropriate join condition there. This Hash shouldn't be too complex even for a medium-sized project.

**Hard approach:** This can be done automatically, if you have `has_many`, `has_one` and `belongs_to` properly defined in your models. You can get the associations of a model using [reflect_on_all_associations](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Reflection/ClassMethods.html#method-i-reflect_on_all_associations). Implement a `Breath-First-Search` or `Depth-First Search` algorithm and start with any model and search for matching associations to other models from your json input. Start new BFS/DFS runs until there are no unvisited models from the json input left. From the found information, you can derive all join conditions and then add them as expressions in the `where` clause of the raw sql approach as explained above. Even more complex, but also doable would be reading the database `schema` and using a similar approach as defined here by looking for `foreign keys`.

**Using associations:** If all of them are associated with `has_many` / `has_one`, you can handle the joins with `ActiveRecord` by using the `joins` method with `inject` on the "most significant" model like this:

```
base_model = "Company".constantize
assocations = [:categories]  # and so on
result = assocations.inject(base_model) { |model, assoc| model.joins(assoc) }.where(query_where)
```

What this does:

- it passes the base_model as starting input to [Enumerable.inject](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject), which will repeatedly call input.send(:joins, :assoc) (for my example this would do `Company.send(:joins, :categories)` which is equivalent to `Company.categories
- on the combined join, it executes the where conditions (constructed as described above)

**Disclaimer** The exact syntax you need might vary based on the SQL implementation you use.

Answer (score 2):

Full blown SQL string is a security issue, because it exposes your application to a SQL injection attack. If you can get your way around this, it is completely ok to make those query concatenations, as long as you make them compatible with your DB([yes, this solution is DB specific](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#pure-string-conditions)).

Other than that you can make some field that marks some querys as joined, as I have mentioned in the comment, you would have some variable to mark the desired table to be the output of the query, something like:

```
[
  {
    "id":"1",
    "className":"Category",
    "field":"name",
    "operator":"does not include",
    "val":"ECommerce",
    "queryModel":"Company"
  }
]
```

Which, when processing the query, you would use to output the result of this query as the `queryModel` instead of the `className`, in those cases the `className` would be used only to join the table conditions.

Comment: Some models aren't directly related to the queryModel

Comment: So for example, I need all the IndividualInvestors of the company. The Company has many Investments and Investment has many IndividualInvestors. How do u propose i'd join these tables?

Comment: Is there any way I could find a association between 2 models?

Comment: That sounds nice. Company also has many Founders and Founders belong to Person. How would I apply it to this?

Comment: So i could do something like `company.joins(:founders).where(founders: {first_name: 'abcd'})`

Comment: No but founders do not have a first_name field. founder belongs to a person who has a first_name. :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157913/discussion-between-mohammad-areeb-siddiqui-and-ervalhous).

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest altering your JSON data. Right now you only send name of the model, without the context, it would be easier if your model would have context.

In your example data would have to look like

```
data = [
  {
    id: '0',
    className: 'Company',
    relation: 'Company',
    field: 'name',
    operator: 'starts with',
    val: 'a'
  },
  {
    id: '1',
    className: 'Category',
    relation: 'Company.categories',
    field: 'name',
    operator: 'equals',
    val: '12'
  },  
  {
    id: '3',
    className: 'IndividualInvestor',
    relation:     'Company.founding_rounds.investments.individual_investors',
    field: 'name',
    operator: 'equals',
    val: '12'
  }
]
```

And you send this `data` to `QueryBuilder`

`query = QueryBuilder.new(data)`
`results = query.find_records`

## Note: `find_records` returns array of hashes per `model` on which you execute query.

For example it would return `[{Company: [....]]`

```
class QueryBuilder
  def initialize(data)
    @data = prepare_data(data)
  end

  def find_records
    queries = @data.group_by {|e| e[:model]}
    queries.map do |k, v|
      q = v.map do |f|
        {
          field: "#{f[:table_name]}.#{f[:field]} #{read_operator(f[:operator])} ?",
          value: value_based_on_operator(f[:val], f[:operator])
        }
      end

      db_query = q.map {|e| e[:field]}.join(" AND ")
      values = q.map {|e| e[:value]}

      {"#{k}": k.constantize.joins(join_hash(v)).where(db_query, *values)}
    end
  end

  private

  def join_hash(array_of_relations)
    hash = {}
    array_of_relations.each do |f|
      hash.merge!(array_to_hash(f[:joins]))
    end
    hash.map do |k, v|
      if v.nil?
        k
      else
        {"#{k}": v}
      end
    end
  end

  def read_operator(operator)
    case operator
    when 'equals'
      '='
    when 'starts with'
      'LIKE'
    end
  end

  def value_based_on_operator(value, operator)
    case operator
    when 'equals'
      value
    when 'starts with'
      "%#{value}"
    end
  end

  def prepare_data(data)
    data.each do |record|
      record.tap do |f|
        f[:model] = f[:relation].split('.')[0]
        f[:joins] = f[:relation].split('.').drop(1)
        f[:table_name] = f[:className].constantize.table_name
      end
    end
  end

  def array_to_hash(array)
    if array.length < 1
      {}
    elsif array.length == 1
      {"#{array[0]}": nil}
    elsif array.length == 2
      {"#{array[0]}": array[1]}
    else
      {"#{array[0]}": array_to_hash(array.drop(1))}
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: It's not necessary to add the relations to the input and he might not want to or be able to add these details into the json input. You can derive all associations by using a BFS or DFS with ` reflect_on_all_associations` as explained in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I feel you are over complicating things by having one single controller for everything. I would create a controller for every model or entity that you would want to show and then implement the filters like you said.

Implementing a dynamic where and order by is not very hard but if, as you said, you need to have also the logic to implement some joins you are not only over complicating the solution (because you will have to keep this controller updated every time you add a new model, entity or change the basic logic) but you are also enabling people start playing with your data.

I am not very familiar with Rails so sadly I cannot give you any specific cde other than saying that your approach seems OK to me. I would explode it into multiple controllers.